# Batch Variable Returned from Powershell NULL

Tags: batch-file, powershell-2.0

I have a bunch of files that I need to rename based on a string inside the file. However, I have to do this from within a batch file and it must be done using whatever is native to Windows Server (Powershell V2). The files all contain the following:
FOOTER SOME NAME I WANT TO KEEP

Since find/replace in regular batch is somewhat weak I used the following Powershell command to extract the desired text and it works pretty well however I can't get the string returned by powershell to persist.

```
@ECHO ON
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%f in (*.pdf) do (
    FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%v IN (`powershell -command "$match = (Get-Content %%~nf.txt)  | select-string -pattern 'FOOTER '; $match -replace 'FOOTER ',''"`) DO set g=%%v
    echo %g%
)
```

From the results, you can see that "g" is set but when I go to use it, it's empty. I've also tried surrounding g with "!". Any ideas?

```
C:\TEMP>(
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %v IN (`powershell -command "$match = (Get-Content A.txt)  | select-string -pattern 'FOOTER '; $match -replace 'FOOTER ',''"`) DO set g=%v
 echo
)

C:\TEMP>set g=SOME OTHER FILE
ECHO is on.

C:\TEMP>(
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %v IN (`powershell -command "$match = (Get-Content B.txt)  | select-string -pattern 'FOOTER '; $match -replace 'FOOTER ',''"`) DO set g=%v
 echo
)

C:\TEMP>set g=SOME FILE NAME
ECHO is on.
```

Comment: Why must it be done using Batch if you have a dependency on PowerShell? Why not just do the whole thing in PowerShell. Your implementation would be massively simpler, and your specific question would simply disappear.

Comment: There are other things going on in the batch file: calling a file comparison program, errorlevel checking, etc. I don't really have a dependency on Powershell but the find capabilities in it are, IMO, superior to those available in regular batch (e.g. Findstr). If I could get Findstr to find FOOTER ABC XYZ and just return ABC XYZ that would probably eliminate the problem as well. Still, I'm curious why the variable is getting cleared.

Comment: The "other things going on in the batch file" can be done in PowerShell also. (It is a shell, after all.) Agree with @RB. that you should reimplement in PowerShell.

Comment: Academic at this point since I found my problem, but when I balanced converting pre-existing 50+ lines of batch code against inserting one call to Powershell, going with the latter was the more attractive option. Maybe down the road I can look into converting the whole thing into Powershell. Thanks for the input though - it did get me looking at the code again which is how I discovered the %% vs !!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem! Doh!

I was using "echo %g%" instead of "echo !g!"

```
@ECHO ON
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
mkdir final
for %%f in (*.pdf) do (
    FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%v IN (`powershell -command "$match = (Get-Content %%~nf.txt)  | select-string -pattern 'FOOTER '; $match -replace 'FOOTER ',''"`) DO set g=%%v
    echo !g!
    rename %%~nf.txt "final/!g!.txt"
    rename %%~nf.pdf "final/!g!.pdf"
)
```